# How can i perform AND operation on multiple bitmaps

Tags: bitmap, clickhouse

I have multiple bitmaps, is there some functions like bitmapAnd(b1,b2,b3,b4....bn) allow me to get AND operation result?

Comment: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/bitmap-functions/#bitmapand

Answer (score 0):

`bitmapAnd` doesn't take more than two parameters, you have to chain the calls:

```sql
bitmapAnd(b1, bitmapAnd(b2, bitmapAnd(b3, b4))))
```

If you have too many of them, and wnat to write it in a more concise way, I would suggest to write use an array and reduce it with the function:

```sql
select arrayReduce('bitmapAnd', groupArray(bitmap)) from bitmaps group by something
```

Here I build the array from the group by clause, but you can do it how ever you want of course.

Comment: I found that groupbitmapand function can be implemented
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/reference/groupbitmapand/

Comment: @lant Oh great, then answer your own question to help others ! I delete my useless answer :)